# When reassigning a Python reference to itself, does it un-assign and re-assign, or do nothing?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, space-efficiency

```
def new_val(x):
    x['a'] = 5
    return x

b = {'a': 2}
b = new_val(b) # b re-assigned to ret val
```

Since dictionaries are mutable, b is a reference pointer to a dictionary, and we pass this pointer into the function new_val.

The reference to the dictionary doesn't change, but the dictionary's reference to 2 changes to 5.

The original variable b should now have 'a' map to 5. However, I'm wondering whether the reference to the dictionary (in other words, the pointer for variable b) ever changes.

We technically, 're-assign' the reference variable b to a reference that happens to be the same.

At a low level, what happens? Is this like a no-op, where some logic recognizes that the reference is the same, or does the reference actually get unassigned and reassigned?

Maybe a simpler example would be:

```
b = {}
b = b # At a low level, what does this line do?
```

Comment: you're returning the same reference, since dictionary is mutable, as you said yourself. There's only one dictionary ever in your code

Comment: But then what does the interpreter do when it tries to assign a reference to the same reference? Does it just ignore the statement? Does the reference get naively un-assigned and then reassigned?

Comment: `b = b` does nothing. It re-binds the data held by `b` to `b` name again

Comment: It's not quite nothing. It evaluates the right hand side, and binds the name on the left hand side to that value. But the overall result is that it has no effect.

Comment: I understand the overall result, but want to understand the process. So there's no optimization procedure whereby the reference is noted as the same, so the code is just ignored?

Comment: "Since dictionaries are mutable, b is a reference pointer to a dictionary," **NO**. The *type* of the object referenced by the variable **has no bearing on the evaluation strategy**. Mutable or immutable is *totally irrelevant to the semantics*. Immutable objects *simply lack mutator methods*. The evaluation strategy is always the same: [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) which is *not call by reference* (which is not supported in Python). You can think of this as "call by value where every value is a reference" if it aids in your understanding.

Comment: Also, really, you should just forget about pointers. *Python doesn't have pointers*. Learn Python's semantics on it's own terms: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html If you come from a language with pointers, you can think of Python variables acting sort of like pointers that get automatically dereferenced when you want them to be.

Comment: I used the concept of pointers here because I wasn't sure what the proper semantics would be. It seems "reference" is the right term for Python, but I always thought that meant pointers under the hood. Thanks for clearing that up for me. WRT the evaluation strategy, "call by value where every value is a reference" seems to be the best way to think about it, "But with an immutable value, no matter how many names are referring to the same value, the value can’t be changed in-place, so you can never get into a surprising Presto-Chango situation." (Thanks for the resource)

Comment: @DaveLiu mostly yes, I'm just saying this because *Python itself does not have pointers*. If it did, you could do things like pointer arithmetic, or dereferencing the pointer. You can't do that in Python. Theoretically, Python could be implemented in assembly, which doesn't *really* have pointers, although variables, pointers, and pointer operations are *higher-level abstractions* that map to assembly-level instructions pretty closely, but they are still abstractions. And again, mostly I just advocate for learning Python on its own terms without borrowing abstractions from other langauges.

Comment: Agreed. Though in the short-term, borrowing abstractions might be useful to convey ideas, it's better to develop a higher fluency in the language of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b = b` is *not* a no-op. The data held by previous `b` variable is reassigned to a new variable, which name is also `b`. So it does nothing but is *not* ignored.

Don't take my word for it. Let's disassemble your last example instead:

```
def f():
    b = {}
    b = b

import dis

print(dis.dis(f))

  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (b)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (b)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you see there are 2 operations `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` on `b` for that `b = b` line. They achieve nothing useful, yet they are executed.

Comment: Would it make sense for someone to try to optimize this procedure by introducing low-level logic that ignores re-assigning references to the same location?

Comment: you can check if `a is b` to see if it's useful to overwrite the reference. But rebinding a new name without checking is faster than testing + maybe rebind.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and thorough answer

Comment: @DaveLiu yeah, I don't see how you could really optimize much, I think needing to check every reference for identity under the hood would end up degrading performance overall.